# ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFoldersAsync(folderName) return ERROR COM call

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have this code for Windows Phone 8 app on VS 2013:

```
public async Task<bool> DoesFileExists(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFolder localFolder= ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                var myFolder = await localFolder.GetFolderAsync(folderName);
                StorageFile file = await myFolder .GetFileAsync(fileName);

                return true;                   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.Source);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This code always get Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component and when I tried this:

```
var playerFolder = await localFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
                foreach (var f in playerFolder)
                    if (f.Name == folderName)
                    {
                      var files = await f.GetFileAsync(fileName);
                    }
```

localFolder.GetFoldersAsync() works fine but crash on var files = await f.GetFileAsync(fileName)
Any help?

Comment: See in the debugger value

Comment: How to find this debugger value? All I found is exception message there is no even inner exception.

Comment: Do you get any other information from the HRESULT? Is there an inner exception?

Comment: No, HRESULT is empty